# How do I change the look of a waypoint I made on the map?

Tags: arma-3

In Arma 3, when I place a waypoint on the map, it is just a normal black dot. I see other people placing different looking/colored ones on the map. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you initially place the marker, but before you save it, you can:

- press Up/Down arrows to change the marker icon
- hold shift with Up/Down arrows to change the icon color

**Pro Tip:**

Your marker's visibility setting will be defaulted to your current chat channel. For example, if your current chat channel is set to Side, then your marker will be visible to everyone on your faction. You can override that visibility setting in the marker's option window that is displayed when you're setting the marker.

In order of least private to most private, the visibility options are:

1. Global (everyone)
2. Side (your faction)
3. Group (your team within your faction)
4. Direct (anyone in proximity to you)
5. Vehicle (everyone inside the same vehicle you are in)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Isn't direct like 40 meters away or something?